# Sendmail milter socket unsafe

Tags: python, sockets, sendmail

I have set a [Python milter](https://pythonhosted.org/milter/index.html) for Sendmail

This is the entry in sendmail.mc according to [sendmail specification](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/adding_mailfilters.html)

```
INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(`pyfilterplain', `S=local:/opt/PCIReaderMilter/Milters/plainMailSocket')dnl
```

I compiled .mc file with m4. Also python milter is running and created the socket

```
srwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       0 oct 11 03:24 plainMailSocket
```

in */opt/PCIReaderMilter/Milters*

Just according to sendmail.mc entry

But when starting `root@myvps# service sendmail start` I get an error:

```
Starting sendmail: 451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 1707: Xpyfilterplain: local socket name /opt/PCIReaderMilter/Milters/plainMailSocket unsafe: Permission denied
```

I've googled and tried all solutions and recommendations, but all seems to be fine in my configuration. This same configuration works very well in Ubuntu 14.04, but not in CentOS 6.7

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up disabling SELinux while waiting for a better solution

Comment: This is the correct option and the only one that resolves this issue across multiple enviornments.

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail checks permission of **ALL** ancestor directories on the socket path - **too broad** permissions are bad for security
(`/opt/PCIReaderMilter/Milters/`,`/opt/PCIReaderMilter/`,`/opt/`,`/`).

You may use one of DontBlameSendmail options **as the last resort**:
https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/tips/DontBlameSendmail/

Comment: All ancestor directories belongs to root and has proper permissions


* drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4096 oct 11 02:03 opt

* drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 oct  6 23:04 PCIReaderMilter

* drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root 4096 oct 11 03:24 Milters

* srwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 oct 11 03:24 plainMailSocket


I think it's a SeLinux issue: When I setenforce 0, sendmail starts without a problem

But apart from the bad idea of disabling SELinux, I don't know what else to do